# How to decrease CPU usage?

Tags: iphone, swift, memory, cpu

I made a Swift app which runs very well on iPhone 6 and 6 plus, but when i test it on an iPhone 5 and below, there are some lags.

After analyzing, I saw a high CPU/memory consumption.

I want to know if there are some tips or best practices to reduce this usage?

I know it is very important to use different threads and return to idle when they are not used anymore, but I already do this.

The code which consumes the most resources creates a container (like the notification center) with some buttons on it and applies a blur effect below them.

Answer (score 3):

When you say

> After analyze, i saw a high CPU/memory consumption

was that using the time profiler instrument?

The Time Profiler will show you exactly what is consuming CPU resources, as well as your usage of the cores on the CPU, thread delays etc.

[Time Profiling with Instruments](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-time-profiling-with-instruments--mobile-9403)

Comment: Yes that was using the time profiler, but i have to confess i'm not familiar with it . I will look at your link, to understand what to do to see what is consuming my resources. Thank

Comment: Spend some time Instruments, it's fun. Check out a WWDC video on it, they  have one or two talks about it every year, not in much detail, but enough to use it and identify what is taking time in the CPU. There are a few options to the right of the Instruments view e.g. hide system libraries which help to show only relevant info

Comment: I started to look a youtube video which give som explanations, it's awesome.

Comment: Instruments is amazing, I think people turn away from it, but its not that complex to use.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this [document](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/OptimizationTips.rst) from Apple to have good tips and tricks on improving performance.

Also make sure you are not doing resource intensive non-UI work on the main thread as this will cause lag on slower devices.

Comment: I will take a look on this document. Thank you Hugo.

Comment: I'd recommend you first make sure you are not doing any heavy computations on the main thread and then look at the document.

Comment: I used instruments to deeper explore which function overload my CPU, and i found that : http://imgur.com/pRIR5zU , furthermore, the ramp-up occur only when my container is drooping.

Comment: I'd be easier to advice on this if you posted the code. That seems like it's the decoding of images from disk that is taking most of the time.

Comment: Effectively images are stored in the sandbox of my app with fileManager, to speed up the loading of my view. I've got an array with some id into, i make a call to a webservice, and I compare what i got from my JSON and what i have in my array. If the Id's are the same, i load images from my sandbox, otherwise i download them. May be it Could be helpful to create a Git repo and send you the link ?

Comment: Use SDWebImage for Image decompression on a background thread. https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: I already use AlamofireImage to improve my code . Is SDWebImage better than Alamofire ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found where the problem was. 
I use a library "FXBlur" to create the blur effect.

This library has a function which update the content of the container every second.

I just modified the code to remove this function, and my CPU usage is now oscillating between 0 and 3 % instead of the 37% that was before.

Thank you everybody for your help.